# Вылетает приложение с Navigation Drawer с CountDown

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Есть приложение с Navigation Drawer, где в каждом фрагменте (вкладке) есть таймер. Если я в одном фрагменте запускаю таймер и переключаюсь на другой (не дождавшись окончания), то по окончанию таймера на предыдущем фрагменте вылетает приложение! Какие есть варианты решения?

Кот таймера:

```
    mButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    mTimer = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    final CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(130000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTimer.setText("It left:" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            mTimer.setText("Care!!!");
            mediaPlayer= MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.move);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    };
```

Код ошибки:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
                                                                             at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:921)
                                                                             at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:904)
                                                                             at fragments.Fragment$2.onFinish(Fragment.java:74)
                                                                             at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:127)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)`

Comment: может код ошибки покажите?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать так, чтобы код в методах таймера срабатывал только если фрагмент виден юзеру и добавлен в активити:

```
if (getUserVisibleHint() && isAdded())
{
    //тут фрагмент виден юзеру.
}
```

т.е. как-то так:

```
final CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(130000, 1000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
           if (getUserVisibleHint() && isAdded())
           {
               ...
           }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
           if (getUserVisibleHint() && isAdded())
           {
               ...
           }
    }
};
```

Comment: Кнопка перестала нажиматься. Может я что-то не так делаю? Там есть выбор: 
Create Getter,
Create property,
Create method "getUservisiblehint". 
Что именно выбирать? @ЮрийСПб

Comment: @ЛевНауменко, я поправил ответ. Там были заглавные буквы пропущены

Comment: Все равно вылетает. @ЮрийСПб

Comment: Может есть ещё какая-нибудь альтернатива?  @ЮрийСПб

Comment: @ЛевНауменко, попробуйте ещё проверять, что фрагмент добавлен в активити. См. обновление ответа.